# How to create an alias email address for the Hotmail domain?

Tags: outlook.com

I am trying to add an alias email address to my current (and quite old) Hotmail account. The current Hotmail service is managed under the Outlook.com umbrella, and it seems like Microsoft won't provide new email accounts under the `hotmail.com` domain. When trying to add an alias, the domain is pre-set to `outlook.com`.

Is there a way to configure an alias under the Hotmail domain?

Answer (score 2):

#### Microsoft won't provide new email accounts under the hotmail.com domain

This is incorrect.

The normal "Create Account" link at https://signup.live.com/signup? allows the creation of @hotmail.com addresses:

> [image]

However, you cannot use new or existing @hotmail.com addresses as aliases (once you create a new one it becomes an existing one for the purpose of aliasing):

> Existing @hotmail.com, @live.com, and @msn.com addresses can't be added as aliases.

---

#### Is there a way to add an alias that is a @hotmail.com address?

No, it is not possible.

> **Use aliases to add email addresses to your account**
>
> ...
>
> You can create up to ten new aliases per year, for an overall maximum of ten. Deleting an alias removes it from the overall count, but not the yearly limit.
>
> **Existing @hotmail.com, @live.com, and @msn.com addresses can't be added as aliases**.
>
> You can create an alias using an existing email address from other providers such as Gmail, Yahoo! Plus, or AIM Mail, as long as you haven't used the address to create a Microsoft account.

Source [Use aliases to add email addresses to your account](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/outlook/add-alias-account)

Answer (score 0):

No. They have removed access to that domain unless you had previously registered a name. They allow you to keep that name, but not add any other.

Comment: Thanks. M$ are champions in taking their best product and systematically destroy the better parts in them...

Comment: Not true. You can still create `@hotmail.com` email addresses. See http://imgur.com/Wcv3iJR

Comment: @DavidPostill - that drop-down box with the domain name selection does not appear in *my* Hotmail menus. If it still possible to create a `hotmail.com` account, do you know of a way to alias that account to an existing account?

Comment: @ysap I was just pointing out that this answer is wrong as you can still create new addresses.

Comment: @ysap. It is not possible to add a `@hotmail.com` alias. I have added an answer.